# Best strategy for displaying dynamic data like popularity in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, yii2

In our application we have to display most popular articles but there could be same strategy required in case of trending, hot, relevant, etc. data.

- We have 2 collections [Articles] and [Comments] where articles have multiple comments.
- We want to display most popular [Articles].
- Popularity is counted basing on some complex formula but let's assume that the formula sums total number of [Articles] views and total [Comments] count. We assume that if formula counts popularity of 1 article then it will take all [Articles] into account to give it also a rank among others.
- As you can see users are constantly increasing views and adding more comments. Every day different articles can be among the most popular ones.

The problem is as follows: how to display up to date data without spamming database with queries?

- I was thinking about scheduled cron job (in our backend app) that would update [Article] popularity for ex. every hour and then save it in article itself. This way when users visit the page nothing would have to be counted and we could just work on saved data.
- There might be also possibility to build a query that is fast enough and counts popularity on demand but I don't know if it's possible.

What will be the best strategy? Count data in background and keep it up to date ,build advanced query or something different?

Comment: I am not quite sure what configuration you do have or how is your data set mounted, but if you had a replica set you might add  a delayed member to the set and pull through your statistic from there. Also, pulling through some data from a very basic structure (as yours) seems to be no a problem to run a query on regular basis.

Comment: Actually the issue that I have is that in order to sort by Popularity I have to count it for every result and then sort it. I am wondering if it's better to add popularity field and count it in cron job rather that counting it on every query execution.

Comment: Oh and I don't use Replica set. Actually looking for simple solution here since It's not a complicated case.

Comment: That sounds feasible too, read a bit about MongoDB concurrency.